# Duplicate values in the output of ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, polymorphism

I am using Jackson `ObjectMapper` to (de)serialize a class with polymorphic nested class. The deserialization of JSON to the class is working fine but when I try to serialize the class to JSON using `writeValueAsString` function I observe duplicate values in the output

```
public class Movie {

    private String movieName;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME,include=As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,property="movieName")
    @JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StarWarsParams.class, name = "starwars")})
    private MovieParams movieParams;

    /* Getters and setters follow */
}

/* Empty class */
public class MovieParams {

}

public class StarWarsParams extends MovieParams{

    private String characterName;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME,include=As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,property="characterName")
    @JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SithParameters.class, name = "Darth Vader")})
    private CharacterParams characterParams;

    /* Getters and setters follow */
}
/* Empty class */
public class CharacterParams {

}
public class SithParameters extends CharacterParams {

    private boolean canShootLightning;
}
```

The code snippet where the conversion is done as follows:

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.setMovieName("starwars");

StarWarsParams starWarsParams = new StarWarsParams();
starWarsParams.setCharacterName("Darth Vader");

SithParameters sithParameters = new SithParameters();
sithParameters.setCanShootLightning(false);

starWarsParams.setCharacterParams(sithParameters);

movie.setMovieParams(starWarsParams);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStringSample = mapper.writeValueAsString(movie);
System.out.println(jsonStringSample);
```

The output, in which `movieName` and `characterName` have duplicates are as follows:

```
{"movieName":"starwars","movieParams":{"characterName":"Darth Vader","characterParams":{"canShootLightning":false},"characterName":"Darth Vader"},"movieName":"starwars"}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you're not doing anything else because I just tried your example with Jackson 2.7.2 and it output the correct JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears with older versions of Jackson e.g. 1.9.2 but not the latest ones from `com.fasterxml`. Jackson identifies 2 fields one from the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation and one from the getter. Two solutions :

1. Use a more recent version of Jackson from `com.fasterxml`
2. Move the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation over the getter instead of over the field e.g.

   ```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "characterName")
   public String getCharacterName() {
       return characterName;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Manos. Issue resolved after I moved the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation over the getter. BTW, I was using the Jackson version 2.2.3

Comment: I tried to give the output of the `writeValueAsString` to `readValue` to convert the JSON back to class. But I got the `Unrecognized field "characterName"` error instead. I also tried with 2.7.0 Jackson version but the result is still the same. Any idea about the reason for this?

Comment: With the latest version of Jackson you can just put `@JsonTypeInfo` over the field. Alternatively add it over both setter and getter

Comment: Thank you. Adding `@JsonTypeInfo` over the field solved it. But looks like I have to use some other library since one of my use case is not supported by Jackson. The issue description is at the following link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

---

**Customized `JSON` Object using Serialization is Very Simple.**

---

I have wrote a **class** in my **project** to get Serialized `JSONObject`. i am giving u a **Idea** to how to Implement this in **Project**.

> Application (POJO Class)

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.webservice.business.serializer.ApplicationSerializer;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize; 

@JsonSerialize(using=ApplicationSerializer.class)
  public class Application  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private double amount;
private String businessType;
private String currency;
private int duration;
}
```

> Now ApplicationSerializer class that contains the Customization using   Serialization Logic................

```
  package org.webservice.business.serializer;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.webservice.business.dto.Application;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

 public class ApplicationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Application> {

@Override
public void serialize(Application prm_objObjectToSerialize, JsonGenerator prm_objJsonGenerator, SerializerProvider prm_objSerializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (null == prm_objObjectToSerialize) {
    } else {
        try {
            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeNumberField("amount", prm_objObjectToSerialize.getAmount());               
            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeNumberField("duration", prm_objObjectToSerialize.getDuration());
            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeStringField("businesstype", prm_objObjectToSerialize.getBusinessType());
            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeStringField("currency", prm_objObjectToSerialize.getCurrency());


        } catch (Exception v_exException) {
            v_exException.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            prm_objJsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Going with @Manos answer for now. Will probably try this out as well.