# Mapping JSON Subobject to field

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to map a JSON object using GSON (via retrofit).

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "id" = 1,
  "artist" = {
    "id" = 1
  }
}
```

I know it can be mapped like this:

```
class MyObject{
  int id;
  Artist artist;
}

class Artist{
  int id;
}
```

Is it possible to remove the extra Artist class and do something like this:

```
class MyObject{
  int id;
  @SerializedName("artist/id")
  int artistId;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you want to delete your Artist class?

Comment: I don't want to delete it, I want to get rid of the reference in this class. (As this class is being saved in my ORM)

Also the Artist object itself contains more fields but the id is the only relevant one in this case.

Comment: You can write a custom serializer for MyObject class, here is a reference http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/

Comment: you want to perform custom Serialization on `class` object and want `JSON` like          {
                               "id" : 1,
                              "artist.id" :1
                              }

Comment: @Hemant  
Sorry, maybe I should have been more clear. I want to DeSerialize an object, not Serialize. Since the data is coming from an api.

Comment: If there is a custom serializer available then custom deserializer should also exists :D Here is the link http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Answer (score 0):

There are two way I know to do what you exactly want to achieve ? One way to write a `CustomizeSerializer` for your own `Class`

> See My **Answer** To This **Question**  **>>**
>   [How To write Custom Serializer For Your POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889314/duplicate-values-in-the-output-of-objectmapper-writevalueasstring/35891474#35891474)
>
> Another Way To Do **>>**  [Google GSON Serializer Examples](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more clear. I want to DeSerialize an object, not Serialize. Since the data is coming from an api.

Comment: have u write two Java POJO's `Artist` and `MyObject` in your Code. Then it will easy to you

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to prevent that